# complex fetch with linq

Tags: c#, linq

My task: You are given a sequence of positive **numbers** and a sequence of strings **stringList**. Get a new sequence of strings according to the following rule: for each value n from the sequence numbers, select a string from the sequence stringList that starts with a digit and has length n. If there are several required strings in the stringList sequence, return the first; if there are none, then return the string "Not found" (To handle the situation related to the absence of required strings, use the ?? operation)

everything needs to be done in one line via linq

I tried this: `numbers.Select(x => stringList.First(y => char.IsDigit(y.First()) && y.Length == x) ?? "Not found");`

but when compiling errors take off

Comment: Can you please provide some data that help to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```cs
numbers.Select(n => stringList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Length == n && y.Length > 0 && char.IsDigit(y[0])) ?? "Not found");
```